# How to add Background rounded line theme to ChipCloudConfig in android

Tags: android

Hi i'm working with using `ChipCloudConfig` in my projects, but i'm not able to make the rounded corner line over the chipcloud background.
can anyone help me here, how to add background style for it.

Here is my actual design right now :
[need to add rounded corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnhtc.png)

Here is my `ChipCloudConfig` declaration :

```java
ChipCloudConfig config = new ChipCloudConfig()
            .typeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.sf_regular))
            .selectMode(ChipCloud.SelectMode.multi)
            .checkedChipColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
            .checkedTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.uncheckedChipColor))
            .uncheckedChipColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite))
            .uncheckedTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

            ChipCloud chipCloud = new ChipCloud(context, flexbox, config);
```

BTW i've declared `FlexboxView` in my layout, in that i added chipclouds dynamically.
Please help me and all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: from documentation it looks like there is no such property. can you link the source where you see this implemented.